# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS freezes too often

Tags: suspend, shutdown, freeze

I'm new to Linux. I was having quite a good experience with Ubuntu from some months. But from some days it is freezing too much. Like it will freeze on using normal Firefox and libre office and the only solution is then shut down by the power button.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.